# how to set range to specific cells

Tags: vba, excel, range

My code currently runs through the first column and finds a certain key word. I want to do another search in the next column with another key word but only for the rows in which the word was found in the first column. I was wondering how I could do this.

Here's my code so far:

```
Set aCell = oRange.Find(What:=firstInput, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If Not aCell Is Nothing Then

   Set bCell = aCell
   FoundAt = aCell.Address

   Do

      Set aCell = oRange.FindNext(After:=aCell)

      If Not aCell Is Nothing Then

         If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then 
            Exit Do

         FoundAt = FoundAt & ", " & aCell.Address

      Else

         Exit Do

      End If

   Loop

Else

   MsgBox SearchString & " not Found"

   Exit Sub

End If

MsgBox "The Search String has been found these locations: " & FoundAt

Exit Sub
```

Basically all the locations returned in `FoundAt` become the search range for the next column.

Comment: This is a good question, but the answer is not obvious. I reccomend you read this: http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/

I have a slightly different version strongly inspired from Sid I can give you, but I'm not sure if I understand the first sentence of your question. If you clarify it would help! (About the order in which you want to search)

Comment: @DavidGM that link helped tremendously. I have made the according change to my code, however I am stuck on something else now. Would it be easier to reach you through a direct message or should i just reedit my post here?

Comment: Re-edit, maybe someone else can help you as well! Unless it isn't linked, then make a new question.

Comment: @DavidGM great okay I made an edit to the page! thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where exactly you're sitting on a solution to this since it sounds like the question has evolved over time. Based on what I understand the question to be, you want to find all the rows in column A that match your search term and then ONLY search those rows in column B for a different search term. So, for example:

```
  A          B
Apple     Cobbler
Cherry    Cobbler
Peach     Pie
Apple     Pie
Apple     iPad
```

If your 2 search terms were "Apple" and "Pie", it would return row 4.

I would accomplish this with a Collection object.

```
Dim myCol As New Collection
Dim r As Integer
Dim FirstSearchTerm As String
Dim SecondSearchTerm As String

For r = 1 To Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
  If Sheet1.Cells(r, 1) = FirstSearchTerm Then
    myCol.Add r, Sheet1.Cells(r, 2)
  End If
Next
MsgBox myCol.Item(SecondSearchTerm) 'Returns 4
```

Of course, this also presupposes that Apple Pie does not appear twice. Eg:

```
  A          B
Apple     Cobbler
Cherry    Cobbler
Peach     Pie
Apple     Pie
Apple     iPad
Apple     Pie
```

Will break this code.

---

Edit: Response to the comment

So now you want to search something like this?

```
  A          B        C        D
Apple     Cobbler    Joe     Blow
Cherry    Cobbler    Joe     DiMaggio
Peach     Pie        Sally   Sparrow
Apple     Pie        Jane    Goodall
Apple     iPad       Ivan    Terrible
Apple     Pie        Sally   Sparrow
Apple     Pie        Jane    Seymour
```

And be able to return row 4 when you have 4 separate search terms "Apple", "Pie", "Jane", and "Goodall"?

At this point you may want to think about restructuring your data! J/K :D

So, instead of adding the value of the cell to the Collection object, we'll add a Row to the Collection object. Then we have to keep looping through our Collection until we have the Highlander (There can be only one!) In essence, we keep juggling back and fourth sifting out the bad data until we are left with only the good. I'm sure there's a way to do this recursively, but its 5 o'clock.

```
Dim myFirstCol As New Collection
Dim mySecCol As New Collection
Dim x As Integer 'Switching to x so its not as confusing
Dim FirstSearchTerm As String
Dim SecondSearchTerm As String
Dim ThirdTerm As String
Dim FourthTerm As String

FirstSearchTerm = "Apple"
SecondSearchTerm = "Pie"
ThirdTerm = "Jane"
FourthTerm = "Seymour"

'First, get all rows matching our first term
For x = 1 To Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
  If Sheet1.Cells(x, 1) = FirstSearchTerm Then
    myFirstCol.Add x 'Just save the row number
  End If
Next

'now loop through that collection search for our second term
'Item(x) contains the row number for rows that matched our search terms
For x = 1 To myFirstCol.Count
    If Sheet1.Cells(myFirstCol.Item(x), 2) = SecondSearchTerm Then
        mySecCol.Add myFirstCol.Item(x)
    End If
Next

'And loop through again for the 3rd term
Set myFirstCol = New Collection 'Reuse it
For x = 1 To mySecCol.Count
    If Sheet1.Cells(mySecCol.Item(x), 3) = ThirdTerm Then
        myFirstCol.Add mySecCol.Item(x)
    End If
Next

'And fourth
Set mySecCol = New Collection 'Reuse it
For x = 1 To myFirstCol.Count
    If Sheet1.Cells(myFirstCol.Item(x), 4) = FourthTerm Then
        mySecCol.Add myFirstCol.Item(x)
    End If
Next
msgbox mySecCol.Item(1)  'Which is the row number matching all our terms
```

Comment: Hi, I was wondering if you could help me with another issue. I have "Cherry    Cobbler    Joe     Anna". How could i insert this line of data into line 2. So i stored each of the first three columns into a collection, but I'm not sure what check I can do on the last column to determine to insert it above line 2.

Answer (score 1):

How's this:

```
Sub test2()
Dim firstInput As String
Dim i As Integer, col As Integer
Dim Rng As Range
Dim check1 As Boolean

firstInput = "cat"
col = 1 ' this will start us off in column 1 ("A")

With Sheets("New") ' using this sheet
   ' There's no reason to loop through ALL columns in Excel, let's just use the columns that are actually in use (.usedrange.columns.count)
    For i = 1 To .UsedRange.Columns.Count 
        Do While Rng Is Nothing 'This will loop until a match is found, or not found
            If col > .UsedRange.Columns.Count Then Exit Do ' if we exceed the used columns, you can stop looking through them
             Set Rng = .Columns(col).Find(what:=firstInput, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, searchOrder:=xlByRows)
             col = col + 1
        Loop
    Next i


    If Rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("Nothing found in this sheet")
    Else         ' When there is a match, do below code
        MsgBox (firstInput & " found in cell " & Rng.address)
        Application.Goto Rng, True
        RowNum = Rng.row
        MsgBox RowNum
        check1 = True
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

This might have a snag or two, depending on how your worksheet is set up.  Just let me know if this works, or what errors you get if not.  Also, any questions just ask!

Edit: Bah - I see that you're searching by rows.  Do you need that to be the case, or is the above okay?

Comment: hi I changed up my question a little now that I got that issue sorted out. I decided to use the find function in excel

Answer (score 0):

@user3242614 said:

> Hi, I was wondering if you could help me with another issue. I have "Cherry 
>   Cobbler Joe Anna". How could i insert this line of data into line 2. So i 
>   stored each of the first three columns into a collection, but I'm not sure 
>   what check I can do on the last column to determine to insert it above line 2.

So if you have the data set:

```
  A          B        C        D
Apple     Cobbler    Joe     Blow
Cherry    Cobbler    Joe     DiMaggio
Peach     Pie        Sally   Sparrow
Apple     Pie        Jane    Goodall
Apple     iPad       Ivan    Terrible
Apple     Pie        Sally   Sparrow
Apple     Pie        Jane    Seymour
```

And someone enters:

```
Cherry    Cobbler    Joe     Anna
```

You want to search for it and enter it alphabetically?

If that's the case, then after each `For x = 1 to collection.Count .... Next` Loop, check the value of collection.Count. If its zero, they have "searched" for something that doesn't exist and so it should be added.

So after the first Collection is gathered, we would insert this code:

```
If myFirstCol.Count = 0 Then 'No values matched
    For r = 1 To Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    'But for subsequent loops you need to loop through the Collection Like this:
    '  For r = 1 To myFirstCol.Count
        If Sheet1.Cells(r, 1) > FirstSearchTerm Then
            r = r - 1 ' The Row the data should be inserted into.
            Rows(r).Insert
            Cells(r, 1) = FirstSearchTerm
            Cells(r, 2) = SecondSearchTerm
            Cells(r, 3) = ThirdTerm
            Cells(r, 4) = FourthTerm
            Exit For 'Jump out..no sense doing more comparisons
        End If
    Next
End If
```

hth